# Как правильно и быстро преобразовать полученные данные сервера в нужную мне модель?

Tags: angular2, typescript

Имеется следующая модель

```
export class ExampleProduct {
  public id: number;
  public status: boolean;
  public name_ru: string;
  public name_en: string;
  public price: number;
  public glass_id: string[] | number[];
  public glass_prices: string[] | number[];

  constructor(id, number, staus: boolen, // И Т.Д) {
    this.id     = id;
    this.number = number;
    // И Т.Д.
   }
}
```

Есть сервис, который получает данные с сервера в виде массива объектов

```
[{...},{...},{...}]
```

И приводит их к нужному нам типу

```
public getItems(): Observable<ExampleProduct[]> {
    const body   = new Body('test'),
          header = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'});
    return this.http.post(this.url, body, header).map(res => {
        let response                = res.json();
        let items: ExampleProduct[] = [];
        for (let key in response) {
            let product = new ExampleProduct(response.id, response.status, response.name_ru, response.name_en, response.price, response.glass_id, response.glass_prices);
            items.push(product);
        }
        return items;
    });
}
```

Можно ли привести к типу ExampleProduct без вот такого вот создания нового экземпляра через конструктор. Ладно мы получаем массив объектов с двумя св-вами, тогда никаких проблем нету. А если приходит объект с 10\15 св-вами? У нас получиться конструктор в модели с полотном свойства + в сервисе у нас та же ситуация в

```
let product = new ExampleProduct(response.id, response.status, response.name_ru, response.name_en, response.price, response.glass_id, response.glass_prices);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете модель, то лучше описывать ее интерфейсом:

```
export interface ExampleProduct
```

и функция уже вернет вам объекты без необходимости их явного создания:

```
public getItems(): Observable<ExampleProduct[]> {
    const body   = new Body('test'),
    header = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'});
    return this.http.post(this.url, body, header).map(res => res.json());
}
```

а если вы используете новый HttpClient, то вместо `map(res => res.json())` надо писать `map(res => res)`

Comment: зачем нам мапить просто так респонс? `Map` необходим для работы с данными, их преобразования.

Comment: в случае c HttpClient не надо :) ошибочка вышла.